# Counting character appearances in Python if we know the predecent character

Tags: python, character, cpu-word

I've a code that counts me the occurrences of a character if we know the precedent character.
This is what I've tried, but it doesnt work.
The file only contains words with the charcters, "K", "L", "G", "A", "S", " ".

```
text = open("fichier_a_compresser 1.txt", 'r')
alphabet = ("K", "L", "G", "A", "S", " ")
for i in text:
    characterlist  = list(i)

j = 0
cont = 0
for i in alphabet:
    for k in alphabet:
        while j < len(characterlist):
            if (characterlist[j-1]==k and characterlist[j]==i):
                cont = cont + 1
            j = j + 1 
        print str(i) + " appears after the character " + str(k) + " " + str(cont) + " times."
        cont = 0
```

I think I'm doing wrong the 'cont' part, because the exit is always 0.
Thanks in advance

Comment: use a dictionary to keep the count, it will be easy that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python's great data structures from the collections module would make your life easier :

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

txt = open("fichier_a_compresser 1.txt").read()

counts = defaultdict(Counter)

for i in range(len(txt)-1):
    counts[txt[i]][txt[i+1]]+=1

for first, counter in counts.items():
    for second, count in counter.items():
        print '{} appears after the character {} {} times.'.format(second, first, count)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code:

```
for i in text:
    characterlist = list(i)
```

possibly doesn't do what you think it does. It assigns characterlist each line of the file, one at a time. When the loop terminates, it has the last line of the file, having discarded all the other lines. Even if you meant to work with only the last line, you don't have to convert it to a list, which I assume is the intent behind `list(i)`. Strings behave like lists already.

As for the algorithm itself, I'm struggling to follow it. I think this might be closer to what you want:

```
freqs = [ (a, b, len(line.split(a + b)) - 1) for a in alphabet for b in alphabet ]
for (a, b, f) in freqs:
    print '{} appears after {} {} times.'.format(a, b, f)
```

where `line` is a string containing the text you want to analyse.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo. It seems that's quite good. The thing is that your, script for example, gives me the exit: "S appears after A 1972 times." and a solution I've from a friend of mine gives me the same thing, but with the words changed, "A appears after S 1972 times". Can be that 'a' and 'b' on your algorithm are changed? Or yours is the proper solution?